# Linq: is there any specific way to run the query?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, linq-to-excel

I would like to know is if I have an excel file and I am trying to get data via linq query will this be posible?

Excel file format

```html
+-----------------+-------------+
| Inputlocation   | Inputvalue  |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 1               | Hello       |
+-----------------+-------------+
| 2               | World!!!    |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Now If I am using Linq query given below is it possible to get Inputvalue data

```
var fileName = @"C:\Users\jshah\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\QA_ExpScript\QA_ExpScript\Excel\Inputdata.xls";
string sheetName = "Input";
var book = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(fileName);
var users = from x in book.Worksheet(Input) select x;
foreach (var x in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x["1"]);
}
```

I am trying to do here is where inputlocation is "1" give me Inputvalue which is "Hello". Am I on a correct way to specify the query?. Also I am using this again and again later in my code. So please give better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` clause to filter the data like this:-

```
var users = from x in book.Worksheet()
            where x["Inputlocation"].Cast<int>() == 1
            select x["Inputvalue"].Cast<string>();
```

Then you can simply iterate through `users`:-

```
foreach (var item in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Inputvalue); //This will print "Hello"
}
```

Although IMHO its always better to create a matching type to avoid any exceptions that can occur by typos when specifying the column names.

```
public class User
{
    public int Inputlocation { get; set; }
    public string Inputvalue { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the query:-

```
var users = from x in book.Worksheet<User>()
            where x.Inputlocation == 1
            select x;
```

Comment: I get it but what if I have to use this again and again then I have to change where clause. Is there any other better option so that even though I keep same query I can extract data from inputvalue without changing where clause. Thanks for the reply in advance.

Comment: The `1` in the code here can be a variable if you want.

Comment: @user3338497 - You can wrap this inside a function and pass the `Inputlocation` as parameter. That is how we do for any generic code right? :) You can accept the answer if that helped you btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda same as I am doing but somewhat answering the question. But don't what which @RahulSingh is saying.

Also related to @Chris 1 in the code. And creator of this post is  i think saying that he does not want to change anythhing in his function. The only change he wants is `Console.WriteLine(x["1"]);` or `Console.WriteLine(x["2"]);` to get Inputvalue

[Reference to my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182430/linq-is-there-any-specific-way-to-run-the-query)